# Testing - How to split up pre-commit unit tests and CI end-to-end tests

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, jest-puppeteer

**Scenario**

I'm working on an app that has fast unit/functional jest tests along with slower end-to-end jest-puppeteer tests. I would like to split those up so that I can run the faster tests as part of a git pre-commit hook and leave the end-to-end tests to be run on CI after the code is eventually pushed to origin.

**Question**

How can I define specific tests to run at pre-commit? Specifically via regex similar to jest *moduleNameMapper* eg `<rootDir>/__tests__/[a-z]+\.unit\.test\.js`

---

- Best idea so far:

in *package.json* add `test:pre` which uses bash `find . -regex` with bash `for do` to run desired "pre commit" tests

Comment: Which part of this are you stuck on? How to run a script pre-commit? How to write the pattern for the tests you want to select (what distinguishes them)? How to pass that to Jest (have you read https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

```
"test:pre": "PRE=1 npm test -- test/pre-*test.js" 
# everything after -- is a kind of regex filter for matching file names
```

to my *package.json* scripts and in my [jest-puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-puppeteer) *global-setup.js* I'm using

```
if(+process.env.PRE) return;
```

before all the puppeteer extras are started. So now I can

```
$ npm run test:pre
```

and violá